# Composer & Symfony - Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3.4 LTS with composer.
My website works fine, but when I try to update any bundle with :

```
php composer.phar update
# or
php composer.phar update symfony/symfony
# or
php composer.phar update swiftmailer/swiftmailer
```

I get this error :

> PHP Fatal error: Out of memory [...] in phar:/// [...]

Below is what I have already tested :

- increase my `memory_limit` from `196M` to `1024M`
- run the composer.phar with `php -d memory_limit = -1`

.. with no success. What else could I try ?
By the way, if I run `free -m` :

```
total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 2002 361 1641 0 7 82
-/+ buffers/cache: 270 1732
Swap: 255 255 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261141/composer-install-keeps-consuming-all-ram-memory

Comment: What do your symfony logs say? They log is probably somewhere like `/var/www/your_project/var/logs/prod.log` or something similar.

Comment: It doesn't generate any logs. If I add the '-verbose' option, I get proc_open(): fork failed Errors

Comment: I can't set more than 1G on the "memory_limit" parameter (hosting provider limitation)

Comment: This an well known composer issue, stackoverflow is full of this ... more memory seems the only real way for first install. Resolving dependencies is a RAM eater. I can't help you due your RAM is limited by your host provider. I would check if the problem is also present on my local (>1GB RAM) machine first with less memory and increasing memory step by step to find out if the memory is really the limiting part and when yes where is the value to go for ... i am pretty sure, if the memory exceeds 4GB and the message is the same, there must be another issue ...

Comment: Install/update on a dev machine, move the generated composer.lock file to the low memory machine and then run "composer install" I have a .5 gb machine and this usually works for me.  Sometimes I also need to reboot just to have as much memory as possible.  Plus you should not be doing updates in production as you never know exactly what you might get.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to copy my website on a local test machine. For the record, it's a minimal new Symfony website with only 12 required bundles ! If 1G hardware memory is not enough to run Composer... what a dumb tool !

Comment: 1gb ram is enough to run composer, it's just not enough to resolve a multitude of dependencies. if you think it's dumb, please do us the favor and implement the smart alternative that uses less ram.

Comment: Run composer update on your local machine. You should avoid using composer update on a server in the first place; use composer install instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer install keeps consuming all RAM memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261141/composer-install-keeps-consuming-all-ram-memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

- Backup website files in local
- Install Wamp and run the servers
- Increase memory limit to 2G
- Make the `composer update`
- Upload the files to the production server

I'm very confusing about composer and its requirements. It's crazy...

Answer (score 1):

use symfony/flex, it embeds optimzations that should reduce the memory requirements of Composer a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 `which composer` update
```

Answer (score 0):

Update composer to latest version with this command,
`composer selfupdate` and then run require command

as mentioned in this asnwer, https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2704#issuecomment-56169024,

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue on my live server.

```
rm -R vendor/
composer install
```

works fine, when composer.json is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer are right but this type of error might also come from the wrong version of PHP install for your windows (32bits or 64bits) as in the below subject:

[Composer update show this error: VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994946/composer-update-show-this-error-virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008)