# Composer update => Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm using XAMPP on a local machine. I couldn't solve this issue by removing the PHP memory limit.

What I already tried :

- modified my php.ini to remove the memory limit =>
  memory_limit=-1
- Checked I was running PHP 5.6
- and self-updated composer to the last version

But it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Does anyone have a suggestion?

My `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "erwin/symff",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "bmatzner/fontawesome-bundle": "~4.4",
        "bmatzner/jquery-bundle": "~1.9",
        "bmatzner/jquery-mobile-bundle": "~1.4.5",
        "bmatzner/jquery-ui-bundle": "~1.10.3",
        "boekkooi/jquery-validation-bundle": "~1.2.1",
        "divi/ajax-login-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "^3.0.1",
        "egeloen/serializer-bundle": "^1.0.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "^2.2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.2.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "ivkos/pushbullet": "^3.3.0",
        "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "^1.17",
        "jmose/command-scheduler-bundle": "^2.0.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "^1.6.1",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1.1",
        "php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.11.0",
        "rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api": "^2.0.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.0.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
}
```

When I run this command:

`composer update`

I get the following output:

```
"C:\DEV\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\DEV\xampp\htdocs\symfony\composer.phar" "--ansi" "--no-interaction" "update"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1584922624) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/DEV/xampp/htdocs/symfony/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1584922624) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/DEV/xampp/htdocs/symfony/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
```

And I expected this to happen:

A simple update as used to happen earlier.

## **EDIT :**

From what I understand, the "Out of memory" error seems to indicate a physical memory limit and not a configured one.

PHP on windows is 32bits (I think so at least...) and 32Bit Processes cannot use more than 2GB of RAM.

So I guess I'm hitting a real physical limitation.

My question now would be : How can I still update my packages on a 32bits PHP ?

I tried updating on a per package approach

```
C:\DEV\xampp\htdocs\symfony>php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update bmatzner/fontawesome-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1592000512) (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar://C:/DEV/xampp/htdocs/symfony/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220
```

but as you can see, I encounter the same problem.

Comment: Maybe you server has old timers?

Comment: And what is "old timers" ? I'm not familiar with this concept.
I'm running a local xampp server (PHP 5.6)

Comment: `modified my php.ini` make sure you modified the right ini file, it's not uncommon to have one named `php-cli.ini` which is specifically used for the Command Line.  So it's entirely possible that you modified the one used by Apache (or what have you) and not the one that Composer will be using.  Your error stats you have apx 1.5 Gb of memory for PHP.

Comment: `old timers` is when you get old and you brain runs out of memory. (it's a Joke)

Comment: There only seems to be one php.ini file.
I just checked this => 
C:\Users\erwin>php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

and got this result => -1

Comment: How much ram does you computer have.  Also exit any other programs, such as Skype, Steam, Browsers, Editors etc.  Which may help free up some more juice.

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix LOL and I was seriously checking google to understand ;-)

Comment: 8G of ram, and about 50% of it is free. I'll try ti shut a few programs to see if it helps, but it still seems like an awful lot of memory would be needed for a simple composer update.

Comment: LOL, I was meaning if you have an Old PC or laptop, Say something like a Pentium 4 with 2 gigs of DDR2 or what every they used circa 1995.  Then you might be SOL.  It's probably more linked to the size of the files that are being downloaded.  But I don't know the inner working of composer much.  Things like max packet size or that one max post size (or whatever it is) my old timers is showing... lol ... might also have some effect.  I usually write my own frameworks, so I never used symphony.

Comment: Are you using Docker or maybe a virtual machine?  8GB should be more than enough.  I have had this sort of problem when using virtual machines with only 1 gb (or even less) memory available.  I suppose you could try removing some dependencies and see if a particular package is causing the problem.  But nothing really jumps out.

Comment: No docker, no virtual machine. If I check memory usage while running the script, It goes up to 1.5G of ram for php cli and I the still have more than 3G of free RAM when the error message occurs

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your machine?  Running out of ideas.

Comment: Turning it off and on again was my first idea too ;-)

Comment: You said there "seems to be only one ini file".  "php --ini" will remove all doubt.  And maybe a "composer self-update"

Comment: I already tried updating composer. Even tried a rollback to my previous installed version without any success.

Concerning ini files no luck either =>
C:\DEV\xampp\htdocs\symfony>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\DEV\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

But I also already tried this just to be sure => 
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update

Comment: If you search for all the .ini files in the xampp folder with the file explorer? I think there is more than one.

Comment: @Dknacht I edited my original post where you can see ini files aren't the problem. Even if they were, this syntax " php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update" would have got rid of the problem

Comment: Yes, you are right. Well I am running out of ideas. Could it be possible it to be a bug of composer? Can you try to paste your Jason in a new file and run composer install and see if the problem rises again?

Comment: @Dknacht I followed your advice and made a copy of composer.phar and composer.json in a new empty folder.

Unfortunately, I get the same error

Comment: unfortunately it looks like "expected case": https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898 but hope there is some workaround unknown yet

Comment: btw do you have `composer.lock` and if you don't could you ask somebody to commit it? memory overhead occurs because Composer tries to build matrix with combinations of every single version allowed. using package.lock definitely should reduce memory consumption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer & Symfony - Fatal error: Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265113/composer-symfony-fatal-error-out-of-memory)

Comment: In this case my clue is to run : `php -d memory_limit=1G composer update ..`

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading to PHP7 did the trick.**

It seems more efficient when it comes to RAM consumption.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me here.

Answer (score 0):

update composer with larger memory limit

`php -dmemory_limit=3G /usr/local/bin/composer update`

Comment: parameters won't have any effect here. As you can see in my comments, I've already tried it. This error message shows a physical memory limit and not a configured one. Seems like 32Bit Processes cannot use more than 2GB of RAM.