# Symfony : Composer out of memory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

so i m using symfony 2.8 (Wamp 2.5 , PHP 5.5.12) on windows 
I'm trying to install the FOSUserBundle 
there is always this error :

```
    cd myproject
    composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
    ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocat
e 16 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/
RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-error
s for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I ve tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked for me

```
php -d memory_limit=-1../composer/composer.phar update
php -d memory_limit=-1 ../composer/composer.phar install

php -dmemory_limit=1G ../composer/composer.phar update --prefer-dist --no-dev 
php -d memory_limit=-1 ../composer/composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev
 php composer.phar self-update .......................................
```

the only way that i could get the FSOUSerBandle installed with this command  `composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"`is to run it outside of a symfony project so it created a `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` folder

And when i ve tried to copy that folder in my project and create a new bundle i get this error

```
 Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in C:\p
```

can anyone help me please ! i ve been searching for a solution for 4 hours now

Comment: And you didn't try what it asked you to try?  https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-error

Comment: yes of course i did ! i ve changed the memory limit in my php.ini to -1

Comment: does the server have xdebug installed? if so, temporarily disable it

Comment: Lots and lots of things you can try from this question posted a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570879/composer-update-fatal-error-out-of-memory

Comment: @Cerad i saw it but i wanted to see if there is a way to fix this problem without upgrading !

Comment: @delboy1978uk i disabled xdebug ! same prob

Comment: Okay, let's think. use "php --ini" to get your correct file and check. Then create a file with phpinfo(); and check the memory limit again. Try to restart your stack, try to restart your computer.

Comment: Upgrading to php 7 fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers ! i upgraded to php7 and it worked !